# Excel adding 1/1/1900 date into certain formulas

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I have a formula that is calculating the number of seconds per action in a formula.  This is formatted as mm:ss.0 for every cell in the column A.  I then try to convert that to number of actions for every minute in column B.  The column B formula takes a number and divides it by the first column.  For some rows it works great but in other cells, the formula is not correct.  As an example, cell A1 says 25:10.0
and results to 0.04.  Cell A2 says 25:16.3 and results to 2.37.  I copy/pasted values and see that in the ones that are not right (A1), Excel is adding 1/1/1900 in front of the time.  I'm not sure how to stop this as all cells have the same formula and same format.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you use time in your formula, wrap it in MOD; e.g. MOD(A1, 1) where A1 holds the time. This will remove any date component and leave a raw time value.

It's possible that the rogue addition of a date component might have something to do with your time crossing midnight.